# How encryption recovery code works?

Tags: recovery

How do recovery codes for lost passwords work? For example, [Nordpass](https://support.nordpass.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002376557-How-to-generate-a-new-Recovery-Code-).

Does it encrypt the current encryption key, so it can be decrypted using a generated key? (Like XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX)

Comment: or it's simply a 2nd key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, no, it's just a key stored in the database that acts just like a secondary password for single use.